# Display tooltips exact format outside, into another div

Tags: highcharts

I want to display my exact tooltips display ( 'LabelName:y.axis' (with legend color)) , into another div (most probably above the chart). And it should be per panehovering (currently having 3 panes). Is this possible?..

```
Highcharts.getJSON('https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-ohlcv.json', 
function(data) {

// split the data set into ohlc and volume
var ohlc = [],
volume = [],
volume2 = [],
dataLength = data.length,
// set the allowed units for data grouping
groupingUnits = [
  [
    'week', // unit name
    [1] // allowed multiples
  ],
  [
    'month',
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
  ]
],

i = 0;

for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
ohlc.push([
  data[i][0], // the date
  data[i][1], // open
  data[i][2], // high
  data[i][3], // low
  data[i][4] // close
]);

volume.push([
  data[i][0], // the date
  data[i][5] // the volume
]);
volume2.push([
  data[i][0], // the date
  data[i][5] // the volume
]);
}


// create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

title: {
  text: 'AAPL Historical'
},

yAxis: [{
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -3
        },
        title: {
            text: 'OHLC'
        },
        height: '33%',
        lineWidth: 2,
        id: '0',
    }, {
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -3
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Volume'
        },
        top: '33%',
        height: '33%',
        offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 2,
        id: '1',
    }, {
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -3
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Volume 123'
        },
        top: '66%',
        height: '33%',
        offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 2,
        id: '2'
    },{
        opposite:false,
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -3
        },
        title: {
            text: 'second AAPL'
        },
        height: '33%',
        offset: 0,
        lineWidth: 2,
        id: '3'
    }],
    
xAxis: [{
        offset: -4,
  lineWidth: 2
}],
    
legend: {
  enabled: true
},

tooltip: {
  split: true
},

series: [{
        type: 'candlestick',
        name: 'AAPL',
        data: ohlc,
        yAxis: 0
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Volume',
        data: volume,
        yAxis: 1,
    }, {
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Volume123',
        data: volume,
        yAxis: 2,

    }, {
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'second AAPL',
        data: ohlc,
        yAxis: 3,
    }]
    
    });
  });
```

This is my working demo [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fvh4gpys/) . This is how my code look like.I want to make the tooltip data to be displayed in other div,so far I have tried, only one data series getting called..

[Visual Representation of desired tooltips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUAC4.png)
I really appreciate any help

Comment: Hi @juniorD, Could you describe more precisely what exactly you want to achieve? Here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fg21j3zp/ you can find an example with a tooltip above a chart.

Comment: hi @ppotaczek thank you for your reply. I have edited my question by adding image link. It is a visual representation of how I would like the tooltips show in <div></div> as user hover.

Comment: I manage to come out with this https://jsfiddle.net/wdh0gn9q/2/ , is it possible to make the tooltips appear in my <div id='tooltips'>'IN THIS DIV'</div>

Answer (score 0):

Use the below options to position a tooltip in the div above the chart:

```
tooltip: {
  ...,
  shared: true,
  split: false,
  shape: 'rect',
  outside: true,
  positioner: function() {
    return {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/akwgf7hm/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.positioner